# Welcome Email is not sending to new customer in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

I'm working in a magento 2. Requirement is to send email on to every new sign up of a client. I have created new template of email and added this template in Configuration->Customer-> Customer Configuration. Also cleared the cache after save config in email. But after all these changes Email is not sending to customer.
Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner and working for the first time in magento 2. So answer briefly please.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spam mail, it might be there. For me this was happening in Gmail.